# @ViewChild is null

Tags: javascript, angular

In my component I have the following:

```
@ViewChild('PaginatedTableComponent') userTable: PaginatedTableComponent;
```

Inside this component I have the following HTML:

```
<pag-paginated-table #userTable
       [(shouldUpdate)]="shouldUpdate"
       [route]="academyMembersRoute"
       [dataStructure]="academyMembersdataStructure"
       [adminActions]="adminActions"
       [include]="academyMembersInclude">
</pag-paginated-table>
```

However, the `userTable` variable is `null`.

Can anyone tell me what I might be missing? Or why this is happening?

**Update**

So this is really odd if i call the function in my `ngOnInit` it shows that the variable is correctly set.

However, if I wait and call if from the following :

```
addUserClose() {
    this.userTable.callRoute();
    this.shouldUpdate = !this.shouldUpdate;
}
```

it says that the variable is undefined.

Comment: @ViewChild('userTable')

Comment: at what line it's saying variable is undefined.

Comment: Remember that Angular will update `userTable` when the child you are referring to goes in and out of the DOM. So it is theoretically possible that it could turn `null` if the element disappears from the DOM due to an `*ngIf`, for example. What is more confusing is why you report it as non-null in `ngOnInit`, which is strange because (1) normally it should not be populated yet at that point in the life-cycle and (2) you have misinterpreted the meaning of the argument to `ViewChild`--it's easiest to make the type of the component (the type itself, not as a string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this is because you are accessing it before it is initiated. Try to access it in timeout with zero time out or access it in or after 'ngOnInit' function has been fired.
Thanks

Comment: i have updated my question pelase take a look if you have time

Comment: Please check and verify that you are not updating the object any where in the class and that element is not deleted or removed from DOM at any state

Answer (score 1):

Have you tries:

```
@ViewChild('userTable') userTable: PaginatedTableComponent; // NOT @ViewChild('PaginatedTableComponent')
```

Answer (score 0):

what you give inside the `@ViewChild('your_Variable')` to be used in html
`#your_Variable`

Change you `component.ts` to

```
@ViewChild('PaginatedTableComponent') userTable: PaginatedTableComponent;
```

And change you `component.html` to

```
<pag-paginated-table #PaginatedTableComponent
       [(shouldUpdate)]="shouldUpdate"
       [route]="academyMembersRoute"
       [dataStructure]="academyMembersdataStructure"
       [adminActions]="adminActions"
       [include]="academyMembersInclude">
</pag-paginated-table>
```